# PowerShell - User Must Change Password at Next Logon

Tags: powershell, active-directory, change-password

Here is what I have, everything works great thus far except the part where I need the user to change their password on sign in

`Import-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\newuser.csv | New-ADUser -PassThru | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText '@To03PXaz4' -Force) -PassThru | Enable-ADAccount -PassThru | Set-Aduser -ChangePasswordAtNextLogon $true`

any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax is `-ChangePasswordAtLogon`, not `-ChangePasswordAtNEXTLogon`. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852287(v=wps.630).aspx

Using `Set-Aduser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true` should fix your problem.

Comment: Well now I am embarrassed! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, please accept my answer if it fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

that's what worked for me:

```
Set-AdUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$true
```

Note: take care of ":" before true