# ChangePasswordAtLogon for LocalUser

Tags: powershell, local

I found this post helpful. [PowerShell - User Must Change Password at Next Logon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493181/powershell-user-must-change-password-at-next-logon)

Is it possible to force a user to set a password on next sign in by using something like this?

```
Set-LocalUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$true
```

I get a NamedParameter error when trying the script above.

What's the best way to force a local user account to reset a password upon login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Set-LocalUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser) cmdlet does not have a parameter `ChangePasswordAtLogon`

Try

```
Set-LocalUser -Name "TheUser" -PasswordNeverExpires $false
```

or use

```
$user = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:ComputerName/TheUserName,user"
$user.PasswordExpired = 1
$user.SetInfo()
```

Comment: Well done. I had not yet found this info and was searching pretty hard.

Comment: Thank you for that info. The first script worked. I haven't tried the second yet.

Comment: Is there any way to populate the ComputerName and UserName values automatically?

Comment: @CrustyPirate For the username you can of course use a variable or loop through a list of usernames. As for the computername.. this is about Local users, so if you want to use `Set-LocalUser` on remote machines, you will have to run it wrapped in a scriptblock and execute it using `Invoke-Command` which has a `ComputerName` parameter. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you @Theo. I'll give that a try! That's really helpful.

Comment: Thank you. It's a bit nuts that this is about the only place I have found where this is documented.

Answer (score 1):

From how it looks, the Set-LocalUser doesn't have a force password change, the post you referenced is for ActiveDirectory users. Looking [at this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/1369575/154867), there is a workaround using net user and wmic that you could code in PowerShell to emulate it:

> Here's what I found worked for me on Windows 10 Home.
>
> `wmic UserAccount where name='John Doe' set Passwordexpires=true`
>
> Followed by
>
> `net user "John Doe" /logonpasswordchg:yes`

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try.